# How to quickly test a Java-method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, debugging, testing

I have a simple method in My Java-code, e.g.

```
private int specialAdd (int a, int b) {
  if(a < 100) {
    return 100 * a + b;
  } else {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to "run/debug selected code" with given parameter values in eclipse? I'd really like to run only this method and view the result for a couple a values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: write a main method on your class, and call your test method.

Comment: To check by running just write a main method and call this method with arguments. If you want to have a test case, take a look at JUnit or Mokito to write a test.

Comment: There should be a way to run parts or the code without writing a main method or a test-class. Writing tests for private methods is also difficult. I really want to quickly check if a function does what I think.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Not Mockito.  What Mockito does is entirely different from anything that would be useful here.

Comment: @DavidWallace It is for Test. not something else.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera - Mockito is used in conjunction with either TestNG or JUnit, not in isolation.  It replaces some parts of a program with "dummy" versions, so that their behaviour doesn't interfere with whatever is being tested.  In this particular case, there is nothing to replace; so Mockito would be no use at all.

Comment: @DavidWallace yes.                       .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there a way to "run/debug selected code" with given parameter values in eclipse?

No, Eclipse needs a regular `main` method or a `@Test` method as an entry point.

When I want to do a "one off" mini test, what I usually do is

```
class YourClass {
    private int specialAdd (int a, int b) {
       if(a < 100) {
           return 100 * a + b;
       } else {
           return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new YourClass().specialAdd(10, 100));
    }
}
```

and then run (or debug) the current class. (Pro tip: type `main` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to expand it to a full main method)

---

As of JDK 9, you can also use `jshell` for this kind of testing:

```
$ ./jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 1.9.0-internal
|  Type /help for help

-> int specialAdd(int a, int b) {
>>     if (a < 100) {
>>         return 100 * a + b;
>>     } else {
>>         return a + b;
>>     }
>> }
|  Added method specialAdd(int,int)

-> specialAdd(10, 5);
|  Expression value is: 1005
|    assigned to temporary variable $2 of type int
```

Comment: What do I have to change in my eclipse preferences that the alt+/ works? I was so sure, that there is a plugin that bypasses writing a main-method. Something like "run method within main()", then a window pops up and you can enter parameter-values - and then the return-value of the method for the given parameters is shown.

Comment: There is no such plugin that I'm aware of. In this case the method isn't even static, so you would have to enter more than just the method arguments. You would also need an expression to create the object to call the method on.

Comment: I may have gotten the default keybinding wrong. Try typing `main` and then hit Ctrl+Space.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your method as unitary test, with JUnit for example. By this way you will be able to test the methods separately.

To use jUnit, add the **`@Test`** annotation to your method. You should add to your method an Asset sentence yo check your method operation/perfomance. For example:

```
   @Test
   public void testHelloWorld() 
   {
      h.setName("World");
      assertEquals(h.getName(),"World");
      assertEquals(h.getMessage(),"Hello World!");
   }
```

Then click on the method and **Run as > JUnit Test**:

[image]

You can download JUnit via Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

First up, you don't want to test a private method like this directly.  If it were public, you'd write two JUnit test cases, one for each of the possible paths through your method.

```
public class YourClassTest {

    private YourClass toTest = new YourClass();

    @Test
    public void specialAddMultiplesSmallFirstAddendBy100() {
        int result = toTest.specialAdd(99, 7);
        assertEquals(9907, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void specialAddDoesNotIncreaseLargeFirstAddend() {
        int result = toTest.specialAdd(100, 7);
        assertEquals(107, result);
    }
}
```

JUnit will record a failure for each of these test cases, if the two arguments to `assertEquals` are not equal.  This enables these tests to be added to a battery of unit tests and automated.

But since it's private, you should instead use a similar strategy to test it via whichever method calls it.  Presumably there is *some* public method in your class, that calls `specialAdd` - by testing that public method, you will implicitly test `specialAdd` too.

Comment: The "test" is only for me. A quick test of code other people have written. Simply to double-check if I missed something.

Comment: It doesn't matter who it's for.  You should still do it this way.

Comment: I don't agree with you. I want to understand the code of others - and that also includes understanding their private methods. Adding a `main()`-method seems to be the easiest way. If I want to understand a brake, I also want to look at the brakeshoe and not only test if the car stops,...

Comment: Then what you're doing is something different from "testing".  Your question led me to believe you wanted to know how to **test**, not how to do some other thing.  If I'm going to buy a car, I want to know that the brakes make the car stop; not that the brakeshoe looks pretty.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private static int specialAdd (int a, int b) {
      if(a < 100) {
        return 100 * a + b;
      } else {
        return a + b;
      }
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + specialAdd(10,20));
    System.out.println("" + specialAdd(11,21));
    System.out.println("" + specialAdd(12,23));
  }
```

This is how you can run the application and see the output.
If you want to debug than first mark the breakpoints.
Than right click your java class and select 'Debug as'-> java application.
You will see your cursor moving through breakpoints when clicking step over from the tool bar.

Comment: How is this answer different from others?

Comment: Mr Madusudan. This also suggest for debugging option in Eclipse. Definitely one can use Junit test case but he want a simpler way to debug in eclipse.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer then.Put your suggestion as text not inside code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Junit without input parameters and output parameters:

```
@Test 
private void specialAdd () {
  // provide the value of a and b
  int a = 30;
  int b = 20;
  if(a < 100) {
    System.out.println("100 * a + b =" + 100 * a + b);
  } else {
    System.out.println("a + b =" + a + b);
  }
}
```

Then, choose the method name "specialAdd" and click the right button in your mouse,choose run --> run junit test.

Comment: All you've done is rewrite the original method.  This doesn't test the original method.  It also doesn't automate the detection of success or failure, so it's not much good as a battery of unit tests.  This is NOT the right way to use JUnit.

Comment: Yes,I just copy his code and there have two points need to take care: First one is  that I forget to change the access level to publics;Second one is Maybe create a test case to use getDeclairedMethod(String) to test the private method is better than modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use test frameworks like testng/junit where you can assert values returned by your method and you could create repeatable tests with them.

But if you want to test it simply with main, you could do the following:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
       int number = specialAdd(99, 1);
       if (number != 9901) {
            System.out.println("Expected: " + 9901 + " Actual: " + number);
       }
       if (args.length >= 2) {//with system args
           int number1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
           int number2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           number = specialAdd(number1, number2);
           if (number != ...) {} 
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can create a Scrapbook page (an file with the extension .jpage)

In there you can write java code an execute like it was in a Method.

https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-create_scrapbook_page.htm

For Example create a `test.jpage` in the package with the class and method you want to test.
In there write your Java-Code

```
int a = ..., b = ...;
if(a < 100) {
    return 100 * a + b;
} else {
    return a + b;
}
```

or you can call Methods of your class.

```
com.mycomp.TestedClass testedInstance = new com.mycomp.TestedClass();
for(int a=0,b=0; b < 100 && a < 100; a++,b++) {
    System.out.println(testedInstance.specialAdd(a,b));
}
```

Sadly imports in this file have to be written out.
You can run your written code by selecting it > rigth click > execute.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19730936)

Comment: @Bentaye Thank you for the reminder, i added an example.